# Return untranslated results from a Play!2 WS call (in Scala)

Tags: web-services, scala, playframework-2.0

I'm writing a play Controller that should call another web service and return its result verbatim -- same response code, same headers, same body.  But it seems like the Controller is written such that I have to specify an explicit return code.  I've tried getting the ahcResponse, but that doesn't seem to provide an obvious solution.

Here's what I have now:

```
def route(name: String, command: String) = Action {

  Async {
    (
      WS.url("someurl").get().map {
        (
          response => Ok(response.body))
      })
  }
}
```

However, this always returns an "OK" status, and if it gets an error, it will pull the error HTML into the body as text.

How do I forward the results of a WS call back to my caller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could forward the response code and body in the following way:

```
WS.url(url)
  .get
  .map(response =>
    response.status match {
       // in case you want to do something special for ok
       // otherwise, pattern matching is not necessary
      case OK => Ok(response.body)
      case x => new Status(x)(response.body)
    })
  .recover {
    case ex: Throwable =>
      InternalServerError("some exception...")
  }
```

Comment: What happens with the request and response headers ?